# Не могу кликнуть на объект в библиотеке selenium(python)

Tags: python, selenium, youtube

Всем привет!
На днях я начал использовать библиотеку Selenium для нажатия на кнопку лайк в youtube, всё было хорошо и тут вдруг не понятно из-за чего программа просто не делает клик и ошибок никаких не выдаёт, хотя я ничего в коде не менял, а когда я попробовал этот же код на другом компьютере, то всё сработало, а самое главное что на других сайтах selenium всё делает, а на youtube нет(

Использую Python 3.5 и Selenium 3.0.0

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'url video'
FILE_NAME_PROFILE = "C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + FILE_NAME_PROFILE)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/chromedriver_win32 (1)/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
like = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//yt-icon[@class="style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer"]')
like.click()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Есть предположение: возможно на пк, где проводится тестирование, в chrome вы не авторизованы на youtube. А так как у вас после like - сразу идет driver.quit() - вы не видите всплывающего меню просьбы авторизоваться. А ошибку не выдает, потому что selenium находит элемент по xpath и даже нажимает на него. Но реального лайка не происходит из-за всплывающего окна. Поставте после like.click() - time.sleep(5) и тогда увидите проблему.

Comment: @Slavakamrad В chrome я авторизован, а время не помогло уже и 10 секунд ставил(

Comment: @Slavakamrad Я пробовал всё тоже самое на другом компьютере и там всё работало, а на моём основном нет(

Comment: Может быть версия chrome старая? Просто я протестил, все работает и правда. Проблема видимо где то именно на пк, а не в коде. Может быть еще убрать options? Они тут особо для проверки не нужны. Вот так у меня все прекрасно завелось:                     from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome('ваш_путь')
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1cSIco9Hsk')
time.sleep(5)
like = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//yt-icon[@class="style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer"]')
like.click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()